# Need help in jquery to rectify image caption fade

Tags: jquery, image, caption

http://www.umairdesigner.com/emagics/

Hi, I'm working on this site I've developed image caption fadeOut and img zoom when mouse over it and opposite if mouse leave tha image area. But i notice when i hover on any image in (Meet the Team, under the about-us section) the first image is also effect likewise. any suggestion would be great appreciable.

Here is the code;

```
    figure.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('figcaption').fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'-20', left: '-20', width: '224', height: '270'});
});
figure.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('figcaption').fadeIn('fast');
    $(this).find('img').animate({top:'0', left: '0', width: '193', height: '233'});
});
```

here is the team section
[image]

Comment: I've also declare a variable for var figure = $('figure');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always provide jsfiddle rather then providing your website url ..**Always**

```
<div id="ibox"></div>
```

Change it to different id's for different boxes.

You can give class = ibox or id="ibox1" ibox2 and so .on ..

```
 <div id="ibox1"></div> or <div class="ibox"></div>
```

Comment: And here is the updated jsfiddle site. But that duplicate effect isn't showing here. you have to visit the above link to check it. here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/HgwPs/1/

Comment: did u tried .as mentioned in answer . i checked and tested that in your webpage only !!

Comment: thanks it now solved. I've comment the $('.team_person img').ibox(); line and it solves the issue. thanks